# Get the id of the photo I posted and get the photo's number of like?

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-like

I try to get the photo ID to request how many like of it ! But I don't know how to do it ! pls help me !
This is how I post my photo !

```
 private void postPhoto() {
        if (hasPublishPermission()) {
            Bitmap image = cg.toBitmap(800, 800);
            Request request = Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), image, new Request.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Response response) 
                {   
                    showPublishResult(getString(R.string.photo_post), response.getError());
                }
            });
            request.executeAsync();
        } else {
            pendingAction = PendingAction.POST_PHOTO;
        }
    }
```

and how to get the number of like of it ( when we have the id of this photo ) . Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

If you post a photo successfully, the Graph API will include an Object ID in the response, like

```
{ id: 1234567 }
```

Now, you can query the likes via

```
GET /1234567/likes
```

Then, you have to count the likes by iterating over the result array, or use an FQL query instead:

```
GET /fql?q=SELECT+object_id,like_info.like_count+FROM+photo+WHERE+object_id=12345667
```

There, you'll have the like_count directly.

Comment: sorry ! can you tell me more ! may be some code can help me ! sorry , I'm newbie of the facebook sdk :(

Comment: Well, there's plenty of sample code in the link, and I gave you detailed info what kind of queries you need to use. I will not write your application for you.